# Math Competition Practice

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

I am studying for the Berkeley Math Tournament (BMT) and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what I should study to prepare. This is my first math competition and would like to have as much practice before hand as possible. Also, taking a look at last years competition there are a lot of problems that I am unsure of where to begin approaching them, if anyone has any references that would help me learn the ideas and mathematics behind the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but: Can you say a little more about the BMT: at what level of education are the participants? Is it geared for high school students, college undergrads, or...?

Comment: High school students
http://bmt.berkeley.edu/

Comment: One obvious point that’s probably already occurred to you: try to solve problems from last year’s competition. Pay close attention to the types of mathematics that you need to solve them, and when you can’t solve one, see what was used in the published solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [***Art of Problem Solving - AoPS***](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/articles.php) website: the link I've given is to the "resources" page with lots of articles geared toward high-caliber students, and those engaged in math competitions.

But there are also many other links at AoPS that are relevant to your interests, so feel free to spend some time exploring articles/tutorials on topics covered in many math competitions, contest and test-taking strategies, a community forum, and links to other helpful resources (books, practice problems (many with solutions from other users), access to questions from earlier competitions, and more. For the main site, see [***AoPS***](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

But practice is key: expose yourself to a variety of problems, try to team up with other interested students to have practice sessions, ask your instructors to supervise/advise...and (did I say practice?)